# Is there a way to make the I-beam cursor bigger or thicker in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssms

Is there a way to make the I beam cursor bigger or thicker in Windows? I can make the regular cursor (arrow) larger by using a different .cur file. In some windows like the query window in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), the I beam cursor in a window with a lot of text is hard to see because the cursor is mostly 1 pixel wide.

Comment: See this, article is for W7 but is same for w10>>>>>https://lifehacker.com/make-your-windows-type-cursor-more-visible-by-increasin-1625023387

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSMS uses the current windows theme 'Text Selector' .cur file.

Try looking for a cursor [here](http://www.rw-designer.com/gallery?search=i%20beam%20cursors&page=1) otherwise you can create your own online, then download and browse to the saved file.

I personally use [this](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-detail/23622) mouse for text reading

[image]